# Check if fields from two different files are not equal

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to create a script that reads user info that updates variables from an original file if there are any changes. I want to omit a variable if its left blank, basically, I want to keep that same variable as it is.

The data format in both files I'm stdout is like this:

```
Nickname FirstName LastName
Hobbies
occupation currActive Inactive
YearsOld
lucky number

The original file looks like this:
WebCrawler Peter Parker
dancing fishing
student 08/09/2019 12/14/19
20
9

Example of the new data read and saved as a temp file is:
WebCrawler Peter Parker
reading movies dancing
Software Jr developer
24
777
```

```
read NickNameTemp
read FirstNamTemp
read LastNameTemp
read HobbiesTemp
read Tempoccupation
read TempcurrActive 
read TempInactive
read TempYearsOld
read Templucky number

Tempfilename=${NickNameTemp}.backup
if [ ! -f $Tempfilename ]; then
    echo "ERROR: course not found"
    exit 1
fi

compareFunction(){
count=1
# here is where my logic is messed up 

while read a b c ; do
if [[ b != FirstNamTemp && c !=LastNameTemp ]]; then
   echo "$a $FirstNameTemp $LastnameTemp " > a.original
fi
count+=1
done
}

compareFunction < NickName.original
```

I expect to change the original data preserving unchanged variables like this

```
WebCrawler Peter Parker
dancing fishing
Software Jr developer
24
777
```

Forgot to mention I am not using grep, sed or awk.

Comment: Why isn't hobbies updated too? It's different in the new file.

Comment: Hey @Shawn because when hobbies are read and contain a blank input then the variable is kept the same

Comment: But it's not blank?

Comment: `I'm stdout` - you are stdout? Are the header lines also part of input? `preserving unchanged variables` - which variables should be unchanged? Can't you just overwrite the file with new data?

Comment: I figure it out, I am so bad at describing problems. Do I delete the question or hide it?

Comment: If you figured it out, post an answer.